# Exception: 319 A latent expression failed during loading, possible unresolved calls

Tags: amzi-prolog

I'm trying to call amzi prolog program from cmd and i get this error after i tip `run app`:

app is an xpl file

Exception: 319 A latent expression failed during loading, possible unresolved calls